# How do I get dynamic public IP if my ISP use CGNAT?

Tags: networking, router, ip, nat, isp

My ISP uses [CGNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), and they told me they cannot provide me with a dynamic public IP and buy a static IP. Is there any way to get dynamic public IP from my ISP?

I have heard of [PCP (Port Control Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_Control_Protocol). Can that be a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your ISP is using CGN then it's unlikely that there is just one public IPv4 address. There will be a whole pool of public addresses that they'll be using for their customers. Whether they perform some "stability" by using a consistent public address for a customer cannot be answered here. You'll need to ask your ISP for that information.

My home connection (DS-Lite based) used the same public IPv4 address for up to one day, but the next day it would be a different address. Some time ago I noticed that the public address seemed more stable, but I'm fully aware that it may change at any time. Theoretically it might change for every single traffic flow…

If you want to see what public address is visible to a web server you can go to websites like http://ip4.me.

Comment: But here in my case, my public IP and WAN IP are different.

Comment: Your own WAN address is irrelevant when you're behind CGN, what is visible on the internet is the public address that is used in the final NAT box.

Comment: Is there any way to do port forwarding? I have tried to forward it doesn't work.

Comment: No, that's impossible with CGN

Comment: What will be the changes in their system when i purchasing a static public IP from ISP. How they can provide me a public IP since they are using CGN. Why should they can provide me dynamic IP with the same setup for static IP. Pardon me if i am wrong.

Comment: I don't know their system, so I can't tell you what they will offer you. Possibly you won't be behind their CGN service when you purchase a static public IPv4 address, but you'd have to ask them to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information. I am sure that my ISP uses NAT for providing IP to me. As you said, i conclude that there is a chance to get dynamic IP if their system allows ( system used for static IP address).